# Delete specific documents while performing Batch Delete in Dart

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I am learning how to perform batch write operations in Flutter(Dart).

I want to batch delete specific documents, I have code (check below) for deleting all the documents in that collection.

```
//Code for deleting all the documents in 'collectionName'

Future batchDelete(
  String? collectionName,
) async {
//null safety
  collectionName = collectionName ?? '';

  // Get a reference to the Firestore database
  final firestore = FirebaseFirestore.instance;

  // Get a reference to the collection
  final collectionRef = firestore.collection(collectionName);

  // Get a list of all the documents in the collection
  final QuerySnapshot snapshot = await collectionRef.get();

  // Delete each document in the collection
  snapshot.docs.forEach((document) async {
    await document.reference.delete();
  });
}
```

My collectionName is TimeSlot. It has a field called start_date which stores the timestamp as datatype. I want to delete only those documents who's time has already passed.

I have an idea that I have to write something like start_date <= DateTime.now then delete all those document. But I am confused how to write that here.

Also there is field called docterId, need to add another condition where only those documents get deleted where authId's docterId == timeslot's docterId.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to delete the documents as a batch, you should not call `document.reference.delete()`, but call `delete` on the `BatchedWrite` object as shown here in the documentation on [batched writes](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions#batched-writes):

```
// Get a new write batch
final batch = db.batch();

// Set the value of 'NYC'
var nycRef = db.collection("cities").doc("NYC");
batch.set(nycRef, {"name": "New York City"});

// Update the population of 'SF'
var sfRef = db.collection("cities").doc("SF");
batch.update(sfRef, {"population": 1000000});

// Delete the city 'LA'
var laRef = db.collection("cities").doc("LA");
batch.delete(laRef); // 

// Commit the batch
batch.commit().then((_) {
  // ...
});
```

Comment: I am still confused. This will delete all the documents who's name is "LA"? 
Also could you please give an example of how to use 'where'? I want to delete some specific documents only (mentioned in my question).

Comment: This deletes the document with LA, which can only be one document. You will need to call `batch.delete(...)` with each document reference from your loop, and then commit the batch after your loop.